# Can't move facebook to sd card by lucky patcher

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat

I have Android Kitkat OS on a mobile which is rooted. After root I had installed Lucky Patcher to move non-movable apps from phone to sd card memory. Some apps moved successfully but couldn't move facebook. It is showing following error while moving facebook-

[image]

[image]

How to resolve this error and move facebook successfully?